# how to confirm whether a vertex has the tag in NebulaGraph Database

Tags: nebula-graph

My NebulaGraph database version is v3.0.1. When I use graph database, I want to check a vertex has certain tag.

I has tried the queries as below, but can't get the right way.

```
FETCH PROP ON tagName 'vid' YIELD vertex AS node
```

I want to know whether a vertex has certain tag.

Comment: This is actually an intresting question(that I had never been thinking about it before) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (v:tagA)
  WHERE id(v) == "foo"
RETURN "tagA" IN tags(v) AS isTaggedTagA;
```

example:

```
(root@nebula) [basketballplayer]>
MATCH (v:player)
  WHERE id(v) == "player100"
RETURN "player" IN tags(v) AS isTaggedPlayer;
+----------------+
| isTaggedPlayer |
+----------------+
| true           |
+----------------+
```